# How to get unique value in array in php?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

How to get unique values in multidimensional array ? We have to get only unique values in multiple array in comma seprated.
check below array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => BAT0002
            [vendor_id] => 1,2,3,4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => BAT0003
            [vendor_id] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => BAT0004
            [vendor_id] => 1,2,3
        )

)
```

**Code:-**

```
$vendor_id = array();
foreach ($rfq_product_master_data_array as $rfq_data_array) 
{
    $product_id = $rfq_data_array['product_id'];
    $vendor_id[] = $rfq_data_array['vendor_id'];

}
$uniquePids = array_unique($vendor_id);
echo "<PRE>";
print_r($uniquePids);
```

**Actual result**:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1,2,3,4
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 1,2,3
)
```

**Expected result:-**

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 1,2,3,4
    )
```

Comment: What you mean by `unique`  all are unique only `[0] => 1,2,3,4
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 1,2,3`

Comment: I want this all unique array merge and get only unique value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to do below modification in `foreach()` and code after that:

```
foreach ($rfq_product_master_data_array as $rfq_data_array) 
{
    $product_id = $rfq_data_array['product_id'];

    $explodedArray = explode(',',$rfq_data_array['vendor_id']);
    foreach($explodedArray as $value){
        $vendor_id[$value] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($vendor_id); //so you can use it further directly.

//if you want comma separated string then

echo $uniquePids = implode(',',array_values($vendor_id));
```

***Special Notes:*** it will give you comma separated string of all unique `vendor_id` in each case, like suppose if you have

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1,2,3,4
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 1,2,6,7
)
```

it will produce:- `1,2,3,4,5,6,7`

Comment: @Devidas  check notes section. I have mentioned one case there. read it carefully and see that you want same output or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use built in array function:

```
$data = //your data array

$res1[] = implode(',',array_unique(explode(',',implode(',',array_column($data,"vendor_id")))));

//array_column : to get single column - vendor_id
//implode : to combine all vendor ids
//explode : to split ids into array
//array_unique : to get unique values
//implode : to combine unique values
```

Then result of all function set to $res1[] array at o index

```
var_dump($res1);
```

**Expected resut in short code:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1,2,3,4
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
$vendor_ids = array();
foreach ($rfq_product_master_data_array as $rfq_data_array) 
{
    $product_id = $rfq_data_array['product_id'];
    $vendor_ids = array_merge($vendor_ids, explode(",", $rfq_data_array['vendor_id']));
}
$uniquePids = array_unique($vendor_ids);
echo "<PRE>";
print_r($uniquePids);
```

Comment: Please never post code-only answers on Stack Overflow.  Every answer should include an explanation with the intent to educate/empower the OP and thousands of future researchers.